# Error while running test code of Kue(nodejs)

Tags: node.js, kue

I have installed Kue and all its dependencies. On running

> nodejs testing.js
>
> The following error appears

```
> > /home/garima/node_modules/kue/test/test.js:3 describe('Jobs', function () { ^ ReferenceError: describe is not defined
    >     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/garima/node_modules/kue/test/test.js:3:1)
    >     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    >     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    >     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    >     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    >     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    >     at startup (node.js:119:16)
    >     at node.js:902:3
```

The test code is the same as available in [kue](https://github.com/LearnBoost/kue).
Is 'describe' not defined in kue?What am I missing here

Answer (score 0):

Looks like for whatever reason it wants to run a test, for which you would need to install kue's dev dependencies. Navigate to the kue root folder (e.g. /home/garima/node_modules/kue) and run npm install there.

Comment: Kue installs its dependencies automatically during initial installation

Comment: It doesn't install dev dependencies unless you run npm install inside the folder.